# ESLint rule to require arrow functions in classes when `this` is referenced

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Is there an ESLint rule to enforce that arrow functions are used in classes, whenever `this` is referenced.

Javascript famously has strange semantics on how `this` is bound to a function.

Sometimes it's desirable to have `this` bound by the caller, however with class methods, it's almost always not what the intention of the programmer was.

It can often lead to unexpected behavior when a class method is used as a higher order function.

**I would like an ESLint rule that will warn me when a class method is NOT defined as an arrow function.**

Contrived example of why this behavior is undesired:

```js
type CelebrateBirthday = () => number

class Person {
    name: string
    age: number

    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
      this.name = name
      this.age = age
    }

    celebrateBirthday(): number {
      return ++this.age
    }

    celebratBirthdayArrow = (): number => {
      return ++this.age
    }
}


function celebrateBirthdayAndPrintAge(birthdayCelebrationFn: CelebrateBirthday) {
  console.log("Happy birthday, you are " + birthdayCelebrationFn() + " years old")
}


const person = new Person("bob", 10)

// works
celebrateBirthdayAndPrintAge(person.celebratBirthdayArrow)
// throws error "this is undefined"
celebrateBirthdayAndPrintAge(person.celebrateBirthday)
```

[TS Playground Link of the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwhA2EBGAnAhsCAhAli4AFgCZohQC8UAFAJQUB8UAdgK4C2SEKAUNwMbw0AZyFQAClyEB7JlADe3KEuZo2EAFxQhwFDiYBzRcrT6Nzdpx5GlfGdpQs+wKSipNVZ+3v0AaKCbNWDi46BWVlQhwhADp3NQoVNWsIgijogISA5IBfXnC+BGR0TFx8YlJaTSDLeWSlFAhgFhRZAGpWyJis8NzkgsRUDFLCEhAAQRQUKQB3BMrzYJQGWvD6xua2jtSu0xzuXu4AMxYmJxwZKH6ijGw8EdIxpiIxXSZgMdMqJDvykDgB4rnJgAMSYmn+1xKP1GoSMtiY0kQ0XgUn0VAARAAJNBgMBkb5lUZ+EBSFj+BpQdFQVpQAn3P6FQbAIGg2jUylQEAQNAoURSeBEdE0fa8fh2YBQSC8i6UJgQWYSaVMDFIKRIdF+ACMAAZhdwAPT6qDTFwAayE-EZxVuhIeTxeenenyl0iY0SuTOGvwmU2mwsNUEIvtEXCmS3RnSgUSgJyIEEOegggstAJuXtGj2erydECoLpk7qtaehpBoQA)

Comment: I'm confused, `this` in class methods is perfectly fine, that's the whole point of classes. You _shouldn't_ be declaring arrow function const arrow functions inside a class.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added a TS Playground link, you can run the example yourself if you don't understand.

Comment: Just use Function.prototype.bind when passing the function as an argument.

Comment: I'm not an expert on ts-eslint but this is an odd requirement and I wouldn't expect there to be an existing rule for it; you might be able to write one yourself. The conventional use of class instances is not to pull methods out of them and call them from another context, but if you must do that, then you `bind()` it first like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbKP2W).  What you're trying to enforce makes sense but it's unconventional, so I doubt you'll find much existing infrastructure that supports it.

Comment: I think the real problem is that TypeScript doesn't have a `--strictThis` flag (see [ms/TS#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968)) so the compiler doesn't catch the mistake in calling `celebrateBirthdayAndPrintAge(person.celebrateBirthday)`... unless you strongly opt into `this` checking *manually* as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mp8qMm), but that's not scalable.

Comment: @jcalz I would beg to differ. The real problem is people are forced to use JS but never took the time to learn how to use it properly. `this` misunderstanding is a large part why TS was forced upon competent JS developers in most professional contexts. People still don't know JS.

Comment: I like to think that I know how to use JS, but I still occasionally get caught out by issues with how `this` works.
I almost never intentionally want caller bound `this`, I think it makes sense that there should be an ESLint rule for it.

Comment: Then open a PR to add one. I doubt it would get accepted as the rule does not advocate good ecmascript practices, which ESLint is for.

Comment: @morganney link to the PR?

Comment: @Magnus Just wanted to say that I think you're completely right and there should be an ESLint rule for this. I'm slightly disappointed with TypeScript now tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lint -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow-functions

I can use with this lint config:

```
 "rules": {
      "prefer-arrow-functions/prefer-arrow-functions": [
        "warn",
        {
          "classPropertiesAllowed": true,
          "disallowPrototype": false,
          "returnStyle": "unchanged",
          "singleReturnOnly": false
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score -2):

Arrow function by design don't bind anything to `this`. So trying to write arrow functions inside of a Class definition means that you can't access `this` which is one of the major reasons for using a class... accessing local data and methods.

An eslint rule to look for what you're asking would effectively break what your Class is trying to do.

Comment: Arrow functions don't have their own `this` but they can close over another `this` that is in their scope, which is what is happening in the example code, I've added a tsplayground link, you can run it yourself.